# What is the difference between the astar_sp and shortest_path_astar  functions?

Tags: pgrouting

I want to ask about what different of function :
"astar_sp" and "shortest_path_astar"  ?

Do you think the query's result from both of them is same or different?

Answer (score 1):

`shortest_path_astar` is a the basic function for the a-star algorithm. Other functions like `astar_sp` are wrapper functions that often simplify but also extend input parameters and further process the shortest path result, usually based on certain assumptions: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#a-star

You can create your own wrapper functions by modifying existing ones. But they all base on `shortest_path_astar`.

Comment: I see. Ok.

Thankyou very much..:) 
I like ur answer mr.dkastl..:)

Comment: Well, it's probably a good idea to then mark the question as "solved".

Comment: oia, i forgot to ask, the result is same, right ?

Comment: The path is the same, but the format of the result will be different.

Comment: hmm, i have try both of them..
and result is :
1. the path is different.
2. the result of length(it's cost, right?) is different when i used length(The_geom) function..

do you know why?

Comment: i think, astar_sp result is close to the right in real location. 
Maybe..(i still explore it)..hmmm